# Conflicting Javascript:Void(0) error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I believe there is a jquery conflict on my site. Firebug points out that there may be conflicting code on the site. The "select state" drop down menu does not work because the javascript is voided. I am new to working with jquery code as well so i do not know where to begin.

[SUBJECT SITE](http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/products-page/checkout/)

Screen shot of Firebug Console: http://postimg.org/image/ir3beizgj/

**I know such message are occurred when the code doesn't find the jquery file but the files is present .**

Stacked Jquery:

```
e()chosen...=0.9.11 (line 9)
e()chosen...=0.9.11 (line 9)
e()chosen...=0.9.11 (line 9)
e(e=select#billing_state.state_select, t=undefined)chosen...=0.9.11 (line 9)
(?)()chosen...=2.0.14 (line 9)
e(r=0)chosen...=0.9.11 (line 9)
a(e=Object[select#billing_state.state_select, select#shipping_state.state_select],   n=function(), r=undefined)jquery.min.js (line 2)

a(e=function(), t=undefined)jquery.min.js (line 2)
e(n=undefined)chosen...=0.9.11 (line 9)
(?)(e=function())chosen...=2.0.14 (line 1)
a(t=[Document /products-page/checkout/, [function()]])jquery.min.js (line 2)
a(e=Document /products-page/checkout/, t=[Document /products-page/checkout/, [function()]])jquery.min.js (line 2)

a(e=undefined)jquery.min.js (line 2)
a()jquery.min.js (line 2)
```

Comment: you are pointing the wrong path for jQuery, just fix it.

Comment: I would if i knew how, what, or where to change it. I've never worked with jquery before so i do not know where to start! @FezVrasta

Comment: Why do you have two `<html>` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right after you include jquery.min.js you have this:

```
try{jQuery.noConflict();}catch(e){};
```

The [`.noConflict()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) removes the `$` alias to `jQuery`, to avoid conflict with other (non-jQuery) scripts that might try to use `$` for other things.

Then later in your script you have lots of (attempted) uses of `$`, for example on lines like this:

```
$( ".tabs" ).tabs();
```

These attempts to use `$()` give the error shown in your screenshot.

Change those instances of `$` to `jQuery` and it should prevent the errors that you're getting. E.g.:

```
jQuery(".tabs").tabs();
```